# Create NLog file checksum

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, audit-logging

We are using NLog and need to implement integrity check of the logs. To make sure that it was not tampered.

We are looking to create SHA-256 hash of the log file once it rolls and store it in the database for the check.

Does anyone know if this is already available by NLog? 
If not what would be the starting point to implement this?
Is there event that we can subscribe that get's called when file is rolled?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if this is already available by NLog?

It is not in NLog itself.

> Is there event that we can subscribe that get's called when file is rolled?

Currently not. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1249) for those events.

> If not what would be the starting point to implement this?

You could make your own target (encapsulating the FileTarget), or wrapper target. [Examples of wrapper targets are in GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/tree/master/src/NLog/Targets/Wrappers)